# Adding multiplie objects to an ArrayList in java

Tags: java, collections, arraylist

I have a class named `Customer` which stores the following objects:

```
 private String CustomerFirstName
 private String CustomerLastName
 private String CustomerID
 private String CustomerEmail
```

now in order to pass data to jasper report, I decided to create an array list which contains these objects, so :

```
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.Collection;

 /* This is CustomerDataSource.java file */ 
 public class CustomerDataSource {
 public static Collection<Customer> loadCustomers() throws Exception {
 Collection<Customer> customers = new ArrayList<Customer>();

 Customer customer = new customer ( 
 /* I need help getting the objects CustomerFirstName / CustomerLastName and etc */
 );

 customer.addBilling(new Billing ( /* Adding billing info */ ));
 customer.getBilling(new Billing ( /* I need to get the object's values*/));
 customer.balOwing();
 customers.add (customer);
 return customers;
  }
}
```

can someone please explain how to add the objects in `Customer.java` to the array list? (and in general since I need to add objects from different files as well. Thank you

Comment: Your already doing it with this line, no ?:  customers.add (customer);

If not, I don't understand your issue.

Comment: @stuntmania my objective is to pass something like this `Customer customer = new customer ("SampleFirstName","SampleLastName","0000","address@web.com");`

Comment: this is wrong `Customer customer = new customer ( `

Comment: what is this billing stuff - can't see that in the Customer class

Comment: that is in another class called `product.java` where the product has a name, price and etc

Answer (score 0):

So as I see your problem in your comment, you want to create a constructor.

In your Costumer class

```
public Costumer(String firstName, String lastName, String ID, String email) {

  this.CostumerFirstName = firstName;
  this.CostumerLastName = lastName;
  this.CostumerID = ID;
  this.CostumerEmail = email;

}
```

So then you can create a new costumer like that:

```
Customer customer = new Customer ("SampleFirstName","SampleLastName","0000","address@web.com");
```

You could even add the costumer automatically to the ArrayList by adding it in the constructor.

Comment: yes, I do have a constructor in my `Customer.java` but I want to dynamically add those objects in the arry list and not like this. since they can be many different customers

Answer (score 0):

From your comment, I am guessing you would like to use a constructor?

You will have to add a constructor on your `Customer.java`.

```
public Customer(String firstName, String lastName, String id, String email){
  this.CustomerFirstName = firstName;
  this.CustomerLastName = lastName;
  this.CustomerID = id;
  this.CustomerEmail = email;
}
```

You might want to make getter/setter methods for access to above variables.

Answer (score 0):

`ArrayList<E>.get(i)` performs virtually the exact same function as `[]` in static arrays. The only difference between the two is that `ArrayList<E>.get(i)` is simply adapted into the object context. In other words, you can dereference it.

First, you'll need to change the privacy of `Customer`'s fields to public to give the `ArrayList<Customers>` object access to it.
Then you'll be able to retrieve your class' fields with simply:

```
    customers.get(index).FirstName //or whatever other field
```

Comment: thanks, so I also have to create a loop to access other fields ?

Comment: No, the fields will need to be retrieved one-by-one in the same loop iteration.

Comment: Wait, sorry, I guess i wasn't paying close enough attention to your original post. (No, I don't know why.) You're wanting to store your objects in `ArrayList` dynamically to keep down memory usage. In that case, call the constructor for `Billing` and pass it directly to `Billing.addBilling() ─ i.e. `costomers.add( new Billing("SampleFirstName","SampleLastName","0000","address@web.com")) and to retrieve it: `public Billing getBilling(){return this;}

Comment: can you please update the code to reflect the loop ? when I try I get bunch of errors

Comment: I don't want to add those objects manually, that was just an example of what each object contains, I want to store the value of object into an array list

Comment: Are You saying you want to pass a field value, e.g. LastName, directly into the ArrayList, like: `customers.get(i).setLastName(String)` or `customers.get(i).getLastName()`? Or, are you just wanting to print out a text report? In the latter case, you can write a `toString()` override in your `Customer` class and have it construct a string that displays all the field values. Also, just a heads up, I noticed `Collection<E>` is an interface not a superclass, so it can't be instantiated and thus, it can't be returned either. So, you'll want to refer to `customers` mostly, as an ArrayList.

Comment: yes, the current value of an object directly to an ArrayList (eg CustomerFirstName / CustomerLastName and etc)

Comment: Okay, well then yeah, that's pretty much how. Write .get() and .set() for each of your fields and reference them as I showed earlier: customers.get(i).setLastName(String). You also may need to write an empty constructor for your Customer class, because the compiler will only add it in if and only if there are no constructors declared, so you can instantiate empty objects to add to your ArrayList. So, `ArrayList<Customer> customers = new ArrayList<Customer>(); customers.add(new Customer()); customers.get(0).setFirstName(FirstName);' would be the basic construction and editing framework.

Comment: can you please update the code to reflect the changes? everything I do will make the program crash,

Comment: I also have the set and getLastName, setLastName in the Customer.java class

Comment: Okay, what exactly is loadCustomers() doing? Is it loading a file into memory? If so, then what kind of file, e.g. ".db", ".txt"...? And does the Customer object solely contain primitive/String fields or does it have other custom objects as fields as well? I'll try to post a new answer with a new code block next time I post.

Comment: I added a few info here : http://pastebin.com/ASzV1fHu - the constructor for the customer is as follow `Customer(String CustomerfirstName, String CustomerlastName, String CustomerID,String Customeremail)` and each object contains the string

Comment: I *need* to know the origin of `loadCustomers()`'s data. Is it a file? Is it information already contained in the or another object? Is it user input? Where is the data coming from? This data is crucial to the context. Besides that, I don't know what I'm trying to code for.

Comment: the `loadCustomers()` create a collection of object. The user enters the data for each customer